# In C++, is there a way I can make a mutable const member variable? Like with the "final" keyword in java?

Tags: java, c++, constants, overriding, final

I'm creating a game engine class which will have a "logger" member.
Like this:

```cpp
class Engine {
public:
    const Logger logger;
    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    void init();
    void start();
};
```

My question is whether it's possible to make "logger" so I can't override the variable, but still modify the object itself?

Comment: There is no such thing as variable overriding in C++. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: It seems in java `=` has a special meaning of "overriding" (as you say) the object. But in C++ it has no special meaning whatsoever. For classes it's just a member function that goes over every field and assigns new values to them. So making an object `const` disables the assignment, just like it disables any member function that could modify the members.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to modify it, but you don't want to modify it. You want it to be const, but you want it to be mutable. Huh!

Comment: In Java, your class objects are pointers with prettier syntax.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I want to be able to modify the members of it and call non-const methods, while not allowing another instance to replace it by assigning to it. My thoughts was overriding the assign operator but that seems unlogical. If you want to understand what I mean better, have a look at what the final keyword does in java.

Comment: @Noud Aha, that makes more sense.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings My goal is to write the engine class in a way that discourages others from just constructing a new logger and assigning it to the logger the engine uses. The logger is supposed to be used as the primary way to print to the console or files of course, but I hope to prevent behaviour that isn't intended like replacing the logger. I'll be fine if I just leave it as a non-const member but I was mainly just wondering if this were possible and how you should go about it.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about it. Just tell people not to do that thing. Or, better yet, make it so that people _can_ do that safely and usefully.

Comment: @NoudZandbergen If you only want to allow certain kinds of modifications to a member, you should make it `private` and allow it to be accessed only through member functions that perform the specific allowed modifications.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sounds good to me. I just started learning C++ coming from java and there's sooo much to get used to. I'm really used to try to program "the right way", so people who look at my classes know exactly what kind of interactions will work and is prefered or not, and so far in C++ it feels like there's a lot more freedom, with a lot more opportunities for things to go wrong.

Comment: That is accurate! Sounds like you're approaching your learning in "the right" way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has no concept of "replacing" variables in the first place, so what you're asking for doesn't make a ton of sense. It would be better to forget Java when writing C++; they are different languages with different paradigms and concepts.

If you want to prevent users of your class from being able to logically "replace" it wholesale, the closest thing to that in C++ is the `=` operator. This actually just calls the `operator=` function on the existing object, though conventionally we typically implement that function to copy *all* the state from one to another, so from a very high-level perspective it could be considered a similar thing.

If you don't want people to be able to do that, make `operator=` be `delete`d (or `private`) in `Logger`. Now there is not even the imaginary concept of being able to "replace" it. Keep its instance non-`const` and every other usage remains accessible.

If it helps, imagine that your class `Engine` doesn't contain a `Logger`, but instead a `Logger*` pointing to some dynamically-allocated object. If it were a `Logger* const` then the pointer would not be permitted to later point elsewhere, though the pointee (the `Logger` itself) would remain mutable. This is the closest thing to Java's reference semantics and `final` that I can muster for this example. *However* I caution against needless dynamic allocation: use this option for mental comparison purposes only!

Comment: Is using a getter that retuns a const reference advised? Do people ever do that or do people usually not care about this problem so much?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your project or goal (no, "don't let people modify `Logger`" doesn't count as a goal; that's one of your implementation decisions) I couldn't really say what would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking does not make sense in C++. Consider this:

```
class A {
  public:
    int x;
};

A a1, a2;
a1.x = 1;
a2.x = 2;
```

Now, we can give `a1` the same value as `a2` by assigning it:

```
a1 = a2;
```

Or we can simply replace `a1`'s state with `a2`'s state one piece at a time:

```
a1.x = a2.x;
```

These two statements have the same effect. Both of them overwrite the state of `a1` in-place.

So no, there's no "final" keyword that disables only *some* overwriting operations on a member (namely the assignment) while allowing other overwriting operations.

In Java, the `final` keyword prevents a variable from being reassigned to refer to another *instance*, but allows the existing instance to be modified. In C++, assignment never changes the identity of the instance anyway, so there is no need for an analogous keyword.